# How do you make a gemfile group for a specific operating system?

Tags: ruby, cross-platform, rubygems, gemfile

I need to install some gems on development only if the developer is on a certain operating system. In my particular case, I want to make a group for Linux.

**How can I make a group for this?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make bundler use different gems for different platforms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642085/make-bundler-use-different-gems-for-different-platforms)