# Gemfile Dependencies for Different Environments

Tags: ruby, rubygems, dependencies, gemfile

So I have particular gems that I want to run on Mac OSX, some that I want to run on Linux and some that I want to run on Windows for my different development environments due to specific dependencies with those machines but I'm not sure how to do this in a gemfile.

Is there a way to set out a specific group (ie. :group => Linux, :group => macosx, etc.) in a Gemfile for different environments?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up just installing all the gems, rather than just the gems I needed for each individual environment. I guess potentially you could set the gems up in different :groups in the Gemfile and then build using Bundler in each environment with --without {xyz env Gem's} but that was more hassle than it was worth. I think having the added gems bloated my application a bit, but at this point it is just nice to have it working on all my different environments.

Answer (score 0):

I have not personally done this but there is information on doing it:

[Google](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ie=UTF-8&ion=1#hl=en&tbo=d&sclient=psy-ab&q=rails%20group%20dependencies%20by%20os&oq=&gs_l=&pbx=1&fp=e93440e096ce03cd&ion=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.1357700187,d.aWM&biw=1535&bih=788), [Similar on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642085/make-bundler-use-different-gems-for-different-platforms), [SO again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6070817/how-do-you-make-a-gemfile-group-for-a-specific-operating-system)

Hope these help.