# Require gems based on platform

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gemfile

I typically use Red Hat Linux during development; There I need to use gems like `therubyracer` and `libv8`. However, there are times I would like to have the ability to develop on Windows and not have these gems.

Is it possible to limit gems in the Gemfile based on operating system?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642085/make-bundler-use-different-gems-for-different-platforms

Comment: This might provide you some info [Bundler platform dependent](https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/wiki/Platform-as-a-parameter)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use groups

```
group :unix do
  gem 'therubyracer'
  gem 'libv8'
end

# when bundling on windows:
bundle install --without unix
```

Comment: @ardavis I just saw this in a project someone did at my job. I have no idea if it works as intended but I figured I'd share: `gem 'libv8' if RUBY_PLATFORM =~ /darwin/i`

Comment: Thanks, that's interesting too!