# Allow bundler to continue if gem fails and isn't required

Tags: ruby, bundler

My goal is to have bundler try to install each gem, but if a gem fails to install (normally due to native extensions), AND the gem isn't required then it proceeds to try to install the next.

I've been struggling with this for a while, and it is due to trying to build `rb-fsevent with native extensions` for `growl_notify` on linux. Any help would be appreciated.

Gemfile:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

def darwin_only(require_as)
  RUBY_PLATFORM.include?('darwin') && require_as
end

def linux_only(require_as)
  RUBY_PLATFORM.include?('linux') && require_as
end

gem 'sinatra'
gem 'httparty', '~>0.8.1'

group :development do
  gem 'shotgun'
  gem 'heroku'

  gem 'jasmine-headless-webkit'
  gem 'guard-jasmine-headless-webkit'
  gem 'growl_notify', require: darwin_only('growl_notify')
  gem 'rb-fsevent',   require: darwin_only('rb-fsevent') 
  gem 'rb-inotify',   require: linux_only('rb-inotify')
  gem 'libnotify',    require: linux_only('libnotify')
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I've struggled with this also.  I've resorted to creating another group, and putting those that fail into that group, then `gem install --without group`.  There are ways to [modify the gem install behavior based on platform](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/RubyGems#How_to_install_different_versions_of_gems_depending_on_which_version_of_ruby_the_installee_is_using) **if it's your own gem**, but if you're not controlling the code, then this the only thing I was able to come up with.  Hopefully, the platforms you are dealing with correspond to your groups for development, production, etc.

I think this is really your issue:
[Make bundler use different gems for different platforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642085/make-bundler-use-different-gems-for-different-platforms)