# Pretend other platform for `bundle install`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler

I am developing with bundler under Windows and am wondering how to create the `Gemfile.lock` for my production environment.

What seems missing are the gems for other platforms. Running `bundle install` on

```
group :production do  
  gem 'mysql2'
end
```

on Windows creates a Gemfile.lock

```
mysql2 (0.3.18-x86-mingw32)
```

When deploying to a Linux environment this is obviously not correct, I would need the Gemfile.lock to also contain the correct result for Linux. I can run `bundle install` on Linux and learn that indeed

```
mysql2 (0.3.18)
```

is the correct gem for Linux. I then manually update the `Gemfile.lock` in the repository to contain both:

```
mysql2 (0.3.18)
mysql2 (0.3.18-x86-mingw32)
```

This works clean under both platforms, but it seems a kludge.

How can I tell bundle to resolve the `Gemfile.lock` for another platform other than the local one? I guess I need something like `bundle install --all-platforms`. What am I missing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make bundler use different gems for different platforms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642085/make-bundler-use-different-gems-for-different-platforms)

Comment: The question is a little bit different, because I do not care to specify different gems for different platforms, but different Gemfile.lock specs. In particular I think it is against what the `Gemfile` should be, that I would have to pin down mysql to 0.3.18 in the `Gemfile` if I really don't care.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running the following commands will fix your issue.

```
bundle lock --add-platform x86_64-linux
bundle install
git add . ; git commit -m fix
```

### Reference

1. https://www.moncefbelyamani.com/understanding-the-gemfile-lock-file/#platforms
2. https://bundler.io/man/gemfile.5.html#PLATFORMS
3. https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/4269#issuecomment-758564690

Answer (score 1):

It would appear this is a [known shortcoming](https://github.com/cowboyd/libv8/issues/77) in bundler and the workaround seems to be to [run `bundle pack` on every platform](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/2283) you need to use.

Comment: The discussion in the links is a little bit about packaging (and for packaging there is actually a solution with --all-platforms). How about resolution? Can I run bundler to resolve dependencies for a platform without installation?

Comment: Generally, deployment is done on a similar platform to development, so I'd just watch the issues I linked to for a solution.